# Run animation before page unload/browser close

Tags: jquery, css, animation, onbeforeunload

When a user closes the browser window, or tries to refresh, a modal pops up behind the browser's default dialog. However, if I try to apply an animation to the modal, such as fadeIn or slide down, the animation and modal only appear after confirming the default dialogue box.

I'm using Bootstrap modal.
This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal" id="holidays-leave-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<!--content here-->
</div>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {

      $( "#holidays-leave-modal" ).fadeIn();      

      return ("Don't leave yet!");  
}); 
</script>
```

Here is a live example of the page:
[Modal on page close](http://dev.majortravel.co.uk/holidays/holidays_test.php)

If I change the Jquery from fadeIn, to simply, 'show', the modal appears at the same time as the default dialogue. So I assume that the animation is being queued. However, I have seen this done where the modal slides in to the page background behind the default dialogue box.

Any idea how I can make the animation play before/while the dialogue box is open? If I cannot use Jquery to animate it, CSS3 animation will do as well.

Comment: That's not possible, basically because the prompt box is modal, blocking any pending script execution. Maybe try using a CSS animation (e.g switching a class) but i guess this wouldn't fix it or be handled differently by each browser

Comment: I know it's possible, as it is demonstrated on this site: [http://www.majortravel.co.uk] - search for a flight, and then once you're on the results page, try and close the window...

Comment: Ya but like i said, they are using CSS animation, not using javascript one

Comment: I don't mind using CSS then! Any tips on how to execute it though..? Would I add a class to the modal in the html or append the class with Jquery?

Comment: e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/2zmuywv9/

Comment: Thank you so much - should I edit my question to include CSS so that you can answer it with your fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt box is modal, blocking any pending script execution. You could use CSS3 animation/transition but it could not work as expected on all browsers (i'm thinking about safari on IOS even i cannot currently testing it).

Here is a simple example, switching on a class in beforeunload handler to turn on a CSS3 fadeIn transition:

**CSS**

```
#fadeLink {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    transition: opacity 4s linear;
}
#fadeLink.fadein {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**js/jQuery**

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {

      $( "#fadeLink" ).addClass('fadein');      

      return ("Don't leave yet!");  
});
```

### -jsFiddle-